# Model is infeasible or unbounded Using python Gurobi

Tags: python, gurobi

Solution count 0

```
Model is infeasible or unbounded
Best objective -, best bound -, gap -
Changed value of parameter DualReductions to 0
   Prev: 1  Min: 0  Max: 1  Default: 1
Number of solutions found: 0
```

I feel that gurobi print this message without solve the model how can I check this issue the lp file is right.
what procedure should I take so I can solve this problem .??

Answer (score 0):

It can happen that a model can be determined to be infeasible without starting the usual branch-and-bound process. This is then usually happening during the presolving step.

You can read more here:
https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360029969391-Managing-Infeasibility